# Replace While Pattern is Found

Tags: java, regex, replace, find

I'm trying to go through a string and replace all instances of a regex-matching string. For some reason when I use `if` then it will work and replace just one string instance of a regex-match. When I change the `if` to `while` then it does some weird replacement over itself and makes a mess on the first regex-matching string while not even touching the others...

```
        pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        matcher = pattern.matcher(docToProcess);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            start = matcher.start();
            end = matcher.end();
            match = docToProcess.substring(start, end);
            stringBuilder.replace(start, end, createRef(match));
            docToProcess = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
```

Comment: have you tried debugging by adding some sysouts into the loop? Also note that `docToProcess = stringBuilder.toString();` will not change the string that is seen by the matcher.

Comment: How do I make it change the string that is seen by the matcher? Because that's actually the problem... I don't know how to update it/refresh it/change to the current instance

Comment: You can't. But you can create a new matcher and assign it to your existing local variable: `matcher = pattern.matcher(docToProcess);`

Comment: Isn't `String newString = oldString.replaceAll(regex,replacement)` what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Pshemo I don't think so, because his replacement is dynamically created by `createRef()`. Since we don't know the regex, we can't be sure the matches are always equal.

Comment: @jlordo Oh, you are right.

Comment: @jlordo: Can you post an example of how I'd do this as an answer by any chance?

Comment: see my answer. Aside from the sysouts I only added the last line. See if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the sysouts I only added the last assignment. See if it helps:

```
// your snippet:    
pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
matcher = pattern.matcher(docToProcess);
while (matcher.find()) {
    start = matcher.start();
    end = matcher.end();
    match = docToProcess.substring(start, end);
    String rep = createRef(match);
    stringBuilder.replace(start, end, rep);
    docToProcess = stringBuilder.toString();
    // my addition:
    System.out.println("Found:         '" + matcher.group() + "'");
    System.out.println("Replacing with: '" + rep + "'");
    System.out.println(" --> " + docToProcess);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(docToProcess);
}
```

Comment: Amazing. I've been struggling for almost a week with this and I just needed to add one line. Analysis Paralysis... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what problem you got but maybe this example will help a little:

I want to change names in sentence like:

- Jack -> Albert
- Albert -> Paul
- Paul -> Jack

We can do this with little help of [appendReplacement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29) and [appendTail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendTail%28java.lang.StringBuffer%29) methods from `Matcher` class

```
//this method can use Map<String,String>, or maybe even be replaced with Map.get(key)
static String getReplacement(String name) { 
    if ("Jack".equals(name))
        return "Albert";
    else if ("Albert".equals(name))
        return "Paul";
    else
        return "Jack";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String sentence = "Jack and Albert are goint to see Paul. Jack is tall, " +
            "Albert small and Paul is not in home.";

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("Jack|Albert|Paul").matcher(sentence);

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, getReplacement(m.group()));
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);

    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Output:

```
Albert and Paul are goint to see Jack. Albert is tall, Paul small and Jack is not in home.
```

Answer (score 0):

If createRef(match) returns a string which is not the same length as (end - start) then the indexes you are using in docToProcess.substring(start, end) will potentially overlap.